# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() does not open the .exe file correctly?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

The following code is what I've written to open an exe file using a Windows Service(VB.NET). What would be the best way to check whether the exe successfully run(I've tried to log `StartInfo` but did not see anything in the log file when I let the service run)?

I noticed the expected outcome via Windows Service is not the same as I open the exe manually by double clicking.

When I open the 'EdgePostSF.exe' manually, it creates a log file in the same destination of where the exe file exist with the name of 'EdgePostSF_(current_date).log'.

But when I use the following code to open it automatically doesn't not give me any error logged to the windows log file as I tried to log any using `FileIO.WriteLog(output)` also I do not see the EdgePostSF.exe log file created as well. After I check the 'task manager' I can see the 'EdgePostSF.exe' is running which confirms the windows service triggered the code and it started the application.

```
Using process As New Process()
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\aglenn\Desktop\DataCollector\DataCollector\DataCollector\bin\Debug\EDGEPostSF.exe"
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    process.Start()

    ' Synchronously read the standard output of the spawned process. 
    Dim reader As StreamReader = process.StandardOutput
    Dim output As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    FileIO.WriteLog(output)

    process.WaitForExit()
End Using
```

Tried reviewing Microsoft DOCS but couldn't find a right solution to my issue.

The reason I've used `process.WaitForExit()` is to give the EdgePostSF.exe it's own time to do the process and terminate(regardless of the time which I've given to Windows Service, currently I'm using 120000 milliseconds).

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you're doing based on a quick reading of MSDN docs, but I think you shouldn't expect to get any text written to the log from your code until the process finishes, since you're reading from the stream synchronously.

Comment: I've mentioned this to you before.  It's very questionable that you actually need to be doing this as a service at all, but at the very least during development/testing do this as a console app.  It is a million times easier to debug.  You may also find that a service does not have, or limited access to a user desktop folder

Comment: @Hursey please advise what did you mean by doing this as a console app? Pardon me if I'm not getting what you try to say, so other than calling the pre-made VB6 exe file inside this service everything else I have included is considered as a console app? Did you mean to get all the outputs to to console line or something? Like in this article : https://alastaircrabtree.com/how-to-run-a-dotnet-windows-service-as-a-console-app/ 
Thanks!